# Ajax не работает с двум формами в Django

Tags: ajax, django, forms

Делал форму обратно связи через ajax. Всё хорошо работало. Нужно дальше было сделать две формы на одной странице. Сделал. Но перестал работать ajax.

Выкидывает вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 139, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view authapp.views.get_followers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Сам код:

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'authapp/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block style %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style/login.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'scripts/parser-ajax.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ unloading_list_form.as_p }}
        <input name="first" type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn_get_followers">
    </form>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ unloading_list_form.as_p }}
        <input name="second" type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn_get_followers">
    </form>
    <div id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="{% static 'gif/ajax-loader.gif' %}" alt="">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .forms import UnloadingListForm
from authapp.management.scripts.parser import Parser
from .models import UserFollowersList


# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    unloading_list_form = UnloadingListForm()

    content = {
        'unloading_list_form': unloading_list_form
    }

    return render(request, 'authapp/login.html', content)


def get_followers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'first' in request.POST:
            username = request.POST['username']

            parser = Parser()
            driver = parser.init_driver()
            profile_users = parser.get_followers(driver, username)

            for profile_user in profile_users:
                print(profile_user)
                user_followers_list = UserFollowersList(follower_name=profile_user)
                user_followers_list.save()

            driver.quit()

        return HttpResponse('')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UnloadingList(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class UserFollowersList(models.Model):
    follower_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    date_download = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import UnloadingList


class UnloadingListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UnloadingList
        fields = ['username']
```

**parser-ajax.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('.btn_get_followers').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/get_followers/',
            data: {
                username: $('#id_username').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loaderDiv').show()
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log('done');
                alert('DONE');
                $('#loaderDiv').hide()
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что у вас GET запрос посылается вместо POST. При этом ваша view обрабатывает только POST. В ошибке говорится, что ваше view возвращается не `HttpResponse` объект.

Что бы отправить POST, необходимо указать `method` в [параметры ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Две формы на странице обычно обрабатываются [по другому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395807/proper-way-to-handle-multiple-forms-on-one-page-in-django).

Comment: Всё равно как-то не очень понятно. Если делать с одной формой и во views убрать проверку `if 'first' in request.POST` , то всё отлично работает. Если я делаю проверку по нажатой кнопке, то ajax не срабатывает...

Comment: всё правильно. в `data` есть `username` и `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, но нет `first`. посмотрите что именно у вас в `request.POST`

Comment: Посмотрел, действительно только `username` и `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. А почему нет кнопки? Хотя я же добавил ее в форму. Как достать ее в `request.POST`?

Comment: `jquery.ajax` аттрибут `data`, там вы перечисляете все значения, которые передаёте во вью. в списке `data` `first` нет.

Comment: Спасибо, вот я  затупил....